# How to resolve this while using WebSphere DynaCache? com.ibm.ws.cache.DistributedMapImpl incompatible with com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap

Tags: java, websphere

I'm trying to use the DynaCache service of WebSphere Application Service. I'm using the below code snippet in my osgi application -

```
 private DistributedMap mapobj = null;
 
try {
  ctx = new InitialContext();
  mapobj = (DistributedMap) ctx.lookup("services/cache/distributedmap");
  mapobj.enableListener(true);
  } catch (NamingException e) {
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }
```

The exception I'm getting is -

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.cache.DistributedMapImpl incompatible with com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap

I'm on WebSphere Application Server, Base Edition v9.0.0.11

Anyone seen this issue before and was able to fix this?

Comment: Most likely cause is that your bundle either contains a copy of the com.ibm.websphere.cache package, or it is importing a different com.ibm.websphere.cache package than the one WebSphere uses. There isn't enough information to tell from the question, so I would suggest you make sure your application isn't somehow trying to provide the com.ibm.websphere.cache package.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since this is an osgi application, I added the com.ibm.websphere.cache package to its dependency. When I was deploying the cba file to WebSphere, it complained about not able to resolve dependency for com.ibm.websphere.cache. So then I added the was_public.jar to the internal repository after which it stopped complaining and got deployed successfully. Following this when I tested, I got this exception. Not sure if I'm making sense.